# How to I set minimum and maximum width and height of the screen of my Python Pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame

I am stuck on how do I set do I block the user to go less than the set screen width and height of my **Pygame** and also block the user to go beyond the max width and height of the display screen in **Pygame**

Comment: Every time they try to change the dimensions of the screen, check them. If they are beyond the bounds you wish, reset it to the min/max depending on what you prefer? Just an idea, but there may be a better way to do it potentially

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just prepare some popular resolutions and then let players choose from them?

Comment: @KarolMilewczyk Can you please provide some code on how to do it?

Comment: @MuditJain posted in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy example that changes the screen size when its minimum/maximum bounds are broken:

```py
#imports
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#bounds definition
STARTWIDTH, STARTHEIGHT = 200, 200
MAXWIDTH, MAXHEIGHT = 200, 200
MINWIDTH, MINHEIGHT = 200, 200

#variables
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((STARTWIDTH, STARTHEIGHT), RESIZABLE)
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:

            width = min(MAXWIDTH, max(MINWIDTH, event.w))
            height = min(MAXHEIGHT, max(MINHEIGHT, event.h))

            if (width, height) != event.size:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), RESIZABLE)

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

The `VIDEORESIZE` event is, as its name says, always released when the screen size is changed. So, when it is released, we want to check whether the user remained inside the bounds and, if not, reset its size.

It has three attributes: `w`, `h` and `size`. The `w` and `h` attributes contain the windows height and width respectivily, after resizing. The `size` attribute is a tuple of `(width, height)`.

When this event is raised, we do of course want to check whether the user remained in our bounds. This we do using the `min` and `max` functions. We use `max(MINWIDTH, event.w)` to determine whether the height is not under the max width, because if the width is smaller then `MINWIDTH`, `MINWIDTH` will be returned. Otherwise, the width itself will be returned. Then we do something similar with that result and the `max` function to determine whether the window is not to big. Then we repeat the whole proces for the height.

Then we check whether the resulting new size is not the same as the old size. If it is, it does mean that the min/max bounds were broken and we need to adapt the size using `pygame.display.set_mode`. If not, this means that we can continue, as the new size remains within its bounds.

Comment: Your Code works for me. Thanks, @The_spider !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are your project's variables etc. but this is just an easy example. In the place of x you put integer from range 0 to quantity of provided resolutions ofc :)

```
resolutions = [(1280, 768), (1600, 900), (1920, 1080)]
picked_resolution = x
window = pygame.display.set_mode(size=resolution[picked_resolution])
```